# How do I change my oracle session to utf8 charset through an odbc php connection?

Tags: php, oracle, utf-8, odbc

I'm using an odbc connection in a php system to access an Oracle DB that uses charset WE8MSWIN1252.

I need to get results in UTF8,

I´ve tried to use

```
        function conecta_odbc(){
            try {
                $this->link = odbc_connect($this->nomeBanco, $this->usuario, $this->senha);

                // trying to change charset below
                odbc_exec($this->link, "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CHARACTERSET=UTF-8");

                if ($this->link === false){
                    $this->result = "Erro ao conectar".odbc_errormsg();
                }else{
                    $this->result = true;
                }
            }catch (Exception $e){
                $this->result = false;
                $this->error = $e;
            }
        }
```

but it raises a warning message with code 'S1000'.

There's any way to do this conversion after connect ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get results in UTF8"?  If the database character set is Windows-1252, the database can only properly store characters that are valid in the Windows-1252 character set.  Are you trying to retrieve characters that are not present in the Windows-1252 character set?  Or are you trying to retrieve characters that are valid in the Windows-1252 character set but you want the strings to be encoded using UTF-8?

Comment: I'm reading valid win1252 characters, but I want the strings coded using UTF-8.

Comment: Then set the NLS_CHARACTERSET environemnt variable to the proper setting, before starting the client program.  For example, NLS_CHARARCTERSET=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8.  (You can set desired territory, region, and character set accordingly.)